# .htaccess doesnt read custom requests

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made `.htaccess` to read `$_GET['ht'] AND $_GET['hht'] as /ht/hht` but now it dont read custom values when I add to url. For example `mydomain.com/ht/?smth=else` - it doest read `$_GET['smth']`. How can I change that?

My `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule .* - [L]

  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2
</IfModule>

<Files ~ "\.inc$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>


<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Add the `QSA` flag to your rewrites (Query String Append, so your rewritten urls will have the original query string appended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've an extra "-z" in your `REGEX`. Also the last two rules can be consolidated. Also you're declaring a variable in the second REGEX that is not in the pattern. Since there is only one set of parenthesis and you're matching beginning and end of string without recursion, `$2` will not be created.

To keep the vars use [RewriteRule QSA|qsappend](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior
>   of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query string, and replace it
>   with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA] flag causes the query
>   strings to be combined.

To stop processing the rules on a match use [RewriteRule L|last](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l)

> If you are using RewriteRule in either .htaccess files or in
>    sections, it is important to have some understanding of
>   how the rules are processed. The simplified form of this is that once
>   the rules have been processed, the rewritten request is handed back to
>   the URL parsing engine to do what it may with it. It is possible that
>   as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or 
>   section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run
>   again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the
>   rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the
>   request process to start over.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?ht=$1&hht=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?ht=$1 [QSA,L]
```